# Selecting text NOT within <p> tags

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a WYSIWYG editor on my site. It creates only a few html tags (p, br, b, i, strike, img, a).
I would like to wrap all texts in <p> tags, so there will be no text without a wrapping <p>.

From this:

```
<p>Some text here. This is ok.</p>
Some text here. This is NOT ok.
<p>Some text here. This is ok.</p>
```

I would like to get this:

```
<p>Some text here. This is ok.</p>
<p>Some text here. This is NOW ok.</p>
<p>Some text here. This is ok.</p>
```

What would be the best method to do this?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

I would like to do this server-side with PHP.

Comment: Which WYSIWYG editor exactly?

Comment: It is jHtmlArea. The code it creates on its own is ok. But I use its pasteHTML function, and sometimes it messes up things. So I decided to fix the messed up string server-side.

Comment: Okay. And is the actual content neatly separated with newlines as in your example?

Comment: I can not gurarantee that. If there are newlines in the text (for example This is \nNOT ok.) I would still like to get this: <p>This is \nNOT ok.</p>

Comment: beware of mixing HTML and regex. It is a path paved with pain and suffering. It promises much: but falls short when you start asking questions of it.

Comment: I think there should be a detection of which tags are submitted and warn the user if there are any combinations of `regex` with `html` or `xml`...

Comment: I know that. Do not want to solve it with regex, you know... just in case... should I use a HTML parser? Which one is able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this with phpQuery.

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($string);
$doc->contents()->not('p')->wrap("<p>");
$string = $doc->html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure if this helps but I foun this on converting HTML to plain text.  You can probably use some of the code into it to filter out text between

tags. http://psoug.org/snippet/Convert-HTML-to-plain-text_36.htm

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this could help me solve the problem above. :(